# Excel 2010 VBA AutoFilter and AutoFilter.Sort criterion not applying

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, sorting

I'm having a heck of a time getting AutoFilter criteria to apply, both the filtering and sorting. I'm trying to get rid of blank rows and filter over multiple criteria - simple, right? Except it doesn't work. I feel like I've tried every hack on the net. To get rid of blanks I've even tried iterating through each row, deleting the row if the first cell in the row was blank (or "", or TRIM(""), etc.) - it was really slow, and it still didn't work. I tried using the Range.Sort Method, which, as far as I can tell, works nearly identically to the AutoFilter.Sort Method except that it doesn't show up when you hit the *Sort* menu button. Attempted methods for filtering and sorting have resulted in either hiding the entire sort/filter range or hiding none of them. With the below code, the AutoFilter and AutoFilter.Sort criterion can be verified via the filter drop-down and sort button to have been set correctly, but the entire sort/filter range (A1:O5000) is hidden and the list is not sorted. Recording a macro of manually enabling either or both shows the exact same code structure that I am using.

Do you see what the issue could be?

My code depends on another workbook (*maintenance-record.xlsx*), so I've uploaded both here:

- http://tyblu.ca/misc/exceltrouble/DRAFT2%20maint-print.xlsm
- [link removed - private info]

VBA:

```
Option Explicit                                             ' checks variables

' Module-level variables

Dim Date_str, Name_str, Unit_str, Work_str, Impo_str, Kilo_str, Hour_str, Reso_str, Note_str As String
Dim Date_fmt, Name_fmt, Unit_fmt, Work_fmt, Impo_fmt, Kilo_fmt, Hour_fmt, Reso_fmt, Note_fmt As String
Dim Date_wid, Name_wid, Unit_wid, Work_wid, Impo_wid, Kilo_wid, Hour_wid, Reso_wid, Note_wid As Integer
Dim Date_col, Name_col, Unit_col, Work_col, Impo_col, Kilo_col, Hour_col, Reso_col, Note_col As Variant
Dim Range_ary, Ranges_ary As Variant
Dim Head_str As String, Head_fmt As String, Head_hgt As Integer

Dim CurrentWorksheet As Worksheet

Public Sub FormatAllSheets()
'
' FormatAllSheets Macro
'
' Recreates all worksheets.
' Formats column widths, data types, and freezes top row on all sheets except "rules".
'


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False              ' turn off screen updates

' Save current sheet and cell selection so we can go back to it when finished

    Dim ActSheet_str As String, ActRange_str As String
    ActSheet_str = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActRange_str = Selection.Address


' Delete existing sheets, except "rules"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("rules").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False               ' turn off notifications
    For Each CurrentWorksheet In Worksheets
        If CurrentWorksheet.Name <> "rules" Then CurrentWorksheet.Delete
    Next CurrentWorksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True                ' turn on notifications


' Clear "rules", reset formulas

    Worksheets("rules").Range("A1:Z100").Delete
    Worksheets("rules").Range("A1:Z100").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(" & Chr(39) & "[maintenance-record.xlsx]rules" & Chr(39) & "!A1)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(39) & "[maintenance-record.xlsx]rules" & Chr(39) & "!A1)"


' Create all sheets (blank), except "rules"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "orig"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "ALL"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "CRIT"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "NEW"


' Set font style Normal so subsequent character width actions are consistent

    With ThisWorkbook.Styles("Normal")
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = "11"
    End With


' LOOP THROUGH EACH SHEET, except "rules"

    Call SetColumnData

    For Each CurrentWorksheet In Worksheets
        If CurrentWorksheet.Name <> "rules" Then
            CurrentWorksheet.Activate

            With CurrentWorksheet                               ' set column formats and widths
                For Each Range_ary In Ranges_ary
                    Range(Range_ary(0)).NumberFormat = Range_ary(1)
                    Range(Range_ary(0)).ColumnWidth = Range_ary(2)
                Next Range_ary

                Range(Head_str).RowHeight = Head_hgt            ' set headings height
                Range(Head_str).Font.Bold = True                ' set headings bold
                Range("E1,F1,J1,N1").Orientation = xlUpward     ' set some headings 90-deg

    ' Set the equations for all cells here, calling the various ranges (Select Case...)
                Dim Formula_str As String
                Select Case CurrentWorksheet.Name
                    Case Is = "orig"
                        Formula_str = "=IF(ISBLANK(" & Chr(39) & "[maintenance-record.xlsx]Sheet1" & Chr(39) & "!A1)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(39) & "[maintenance-record.xlsx]Sheet1" & Chr(39) & "!A1)"
                    Case Is = "rules"
                        MsgBox "We shouldn't be iterating through 'rules'!!"
                    Case Is = "NEW"
                        Formula_str = "=IF(ROW(orig!A1)=1,orig!A1,IF(OR(ISERROR(orig!$A1),ISBLANK(orig!$A1),orig!$A1=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",orig!$J1=" & Chr(34) & "Y" & Chr(34) & "), TRIM(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "),IF((TODAY()-orig!$A1)<rules!$B$9,orig!A1, TRIM(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "))))"
                    Case Is = "CRIT"
                        Formula_str = "=IF(ROW(orig!A1)=1,orig!A1,IF(OR(ISERROR(orig!$A1),ISBLANK(orig!$A1),orig!$A1=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",orig!$J1=" & Chr(34) & "Y" & Chr(34) & "), TRIM(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "),IF(OR(AND(orig!$N1=" & Chr(34) & "HIGH" & Chr(34) & ",(TODAY()-orig!$A1)>rules!$B$6),AND(orig!$N1=" & Chr(34) & "MED" & Chr(34) & ",(TODAY()-orig!$A1)>rules!$B$5),AND(orig!$N1=" & Chr(34) & "LOW" & Chr(34) & ",(TODAY()-orig!$A1)>rules!$B$4),AND(orig!$N1=" & Chr(34) & "WAIT" & Chr(34) & ",(TODAY()-orig!$A1)>rules!$B$3)),orig!A1, TRIM(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "))))"
                    Case Is = "ALL"
                        Formula_str = "=IF(ROW(orig!A1)=1,orig!A1,IF(OR(ISERROR(orig!$A1),ISBLANK(orig!$A1),orig!$A1=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",orig!$J1=" & Chr(34) & "Y" & Chr(34) & "), TRIM(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "),orig!A1))"
                    Case Else
                        Formula_str = ""
                End Select
                Range("A1:O5000").Formula = Formula_str

    ' Set headings text
                Range("A1:O1").Value = Array( _
                    "report date", _
                    "reported by", _
                    "unit", _
                    "work required / work completed", _
                    "importance - original", _
                    "importance - supervisor", _
                    "work date", _
                    "kilometers", _
                    "hours", _
                    "Resolved?", _
                    "assigned to", _
                    "Shop Manager review date", _
                    "notes", _
                    "importance - overall", _
                    "importance - numeric" _
                )

    ' Format all cells except the headings
                With Range("A2:O5000")
                    .WrapText = True
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = False
                    .Rows.AutoFit
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                End With

    ' Set custom sorting for each page, except "rules"
'                .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
'                .Sort.SortFields.Clear
'                .Sort.SetRange Range("A1:O5000")
'                Select Case CurrentWorksheet.Name
'                    Case Is = "NEW"
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O2:O5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                    Case Is = "CRIT"
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O2:O5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                    Case Is = "ALL"
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O2:O5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'                End Select
'                .Sort.Header = xlYes
'                .Sort.MatchCase = False
'                .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
'                .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
'                .Sort.Apply

'    ' Set custom sorting for each page, except "rules", using AutoFilter
                .AutoFilterMode = False                 ' clear previous filters... shouldn't make a difference
                .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter
                If .Name = "NEW" Then
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O2:O5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                ElseIf .Name = "CRIT" Then
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O2:O5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                ElseIf .Name = "ALL" Then
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O2:O5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                Else
                End If
                .AutoFilter.Sort.Header = xlYes
                .AutoFilter.Sort.MatchCase = False
                .AutoFilter.Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .AutoFilter.Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .AutoFilter.Sort.Apply

    ' Filter out blank rows for each page, except "rules"
                .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

            End With

        End If
    Next CurrentWorksheet


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True              ' turn on screen updates


' Go back to the original sheet and selection

    Worksheets(ActSheet_str).Activate
    Worksheets(ActSheet_str).Range(ActRange_str).Select


    MsgBox "Finished."

End Sub

Sub SetColumnData()

'Define column formats and ranges for all sheets, except "rules"
    Date_str = "A:A,G:G,L:L"            ' column range
    Date_fmt = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"  ' custom number format
    Date_wid = 19                       ' width in characters (zeroes in font style Normal)
    Name_str = "B:B,K:K"
    Name_fmt = "@"
    Name_wid = 18
    Unit_str = "C:C"
    Unit_wid = 6
    Work_str = "D:D"
    Work_wid = 66
    Impo_str = "E:E,F:F,N:N"
    Impo_wid = 5
    Kilo_str = "H:H"
    Kilo_wid = 10
    Hour_str = "I:I"
    Hour_wid = 9
    Reso_str = "J:J"
    Reso_wid = 4
    Note_str = "M:M"
    Note_wid = 50
    Head_str = "A1:N1"
    Head_hgt = 120

    Date_col = Array(Date_str, Date_fmt, Date_wid)
    Name_col = Array(Name_str, Name_fmt, Name_wid)
    Unit_col = Array(Unit_str, Unit_fmt, Unit_wid)
    Work_col = Array(Work_str, Work_fmt, Work_wid)
    Impo_col = Array(Impo_str, Impo_fmt, Impo_wid)
    Kilo_col = Array(Kilo_str, Kilo_fmt, Kilo_wid)
    Hour_col = Array(Hour_str, Hour_fmt, Hour_wid)
    Reso_col = Array(Reso_str, Reso_fmt, Reso_wid)
    Note_col = Array(Note_str, Note_fmt, Note_wid)

    Ranges_ary = Array(Date_col, Name_col, Unit_col, Work_col, Impo_col, Kilo_col, Hour_col, Reso_col, Note_col)

End Sub
```

If you're curious, this is a maintenance tracking system I've developed for a small boom truck and transport company. These sheets need to be tamper-proof, as up to a dozen computer novices use them on a daily basis, so I've hard-coded the formatting, filtering, sorting, and equations into the hidden vba scripts. It's far from perfect, but it mostly works. I'm just a supervisor that really needed a solution to neglected equipment.

Comment: Try changing all instances of `Range("...")` to `.Range("...")`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Changing Range --> .Range did not change behaviour, as far as I can tell, @Kyle.

Comment: I don't get any pop-up errors, @Raystafarian. Hopefully there's no debug console I don't know about...

Comment: I can't reproduce. Comment out the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` line and step through your code to see where it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: I do see an issue, @Kyle. It looks like the data from _maintenance-record.xlsx_ is not updating until after the filtering and sorting is applied. A bit of research into this shows several better methods for getting values from one workbook to another. I'll have to change quite a bit. Thank you very much for the direction.

Comment: I've taken _maintenance-record.xlsx_ down as it contains some private info (and I might get in trouble).